# textDirection is not making the edittext right to left

Tags: android, kotlin, right-to-left

I am creating an app for which I need the text rtl i.e. for Arabic below is my code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_24"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_36"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_24"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/hint_text_color"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_16" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

But Still, I am getting this below UI only

[image]

I also changed the app locale to ar but still the same.

Comment: Did you try typing in Arabic. Put `@string/password` in `values-ar/strings.xml` as well and it should be in Arabic, ie. `كلمه السر` then you will see the text direction change. Also, remove the `textAlignment` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Please try :

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

in TextInputEditText. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

First, Add RTL support to the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Second, Set the selected locale inside your activity,

```
   @Override
       protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    MyMainApp.getAppCompInjector().inject(this);
    super.attachBaseContext(getUpdatedContext(newBase,"ar"));
     }

    private Context getUpdatedContext(Context context, String language) 
    {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language); // ar, en, fr, etc
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue in the past what I did was I used the gravity attribute in the TextInputEditText element like so.

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Bipin Tiwari answer , you should allow rtl in application manifest not this specific xml , and change locale to arabic and it should work